# Returning to Main when using an interface in C#

Tags: c#

So I've created a blackjack game using an interface whose entry point is "PlayGames()". However, once the game is finished, I want to give the option to the user to go back to the main menu, which is in Main(). Is there a way to call main so that the user can go back to the main menu? Simply calling Main() does not work.

Here's what I've got:

```
public void PlayGames ()
    {
        String replay = "";
        var a = PlayBlackjack (r, replay);
        Console.WriteLine ();
        while (a == "yes") {
            a = PlayBlackjack (r, replay);
            if (a == "no") {
                Console.WriteLine ("Okay, goodbye!");
                return;
            }
        }
        if (a == "z") {
            Main ();
        }
    }
```

The variable a is the string user-entered string that determines if the game closes, or continues to play. If the user enters that they want to go back to the main menu, the letter "z" is assigned to a, which will lead them back to the main menu.

Here's what Main() looks like, including class information. The error message that comes up says "Main does not exist in the current context":

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace IntroCS
{
    public class PlayCasino
    {
        private static Random rand = new Random();
        private static List<Casino> games;

        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("MAIN MENU");
            Console.WriteLine ("(0 for help)");
            Console.WriteLine ("(1 for blackjack)");
            Console.WriteLine ("(2 for Quarter Game)");
            int n = UIF.PromptInt ("Please enter an integer to choose your game: ");
            games = new List<Casino> ();
            games.Add (new HelpMenu ());
            games.Add (new BlackJack ());
            games.Add (new QuarterGame ());
            if (n == 0) {
                Console.WriteLine ("Accessing the Help Menu!" + "\n");// this is where we will print directions/ help menus
            }
            if (n == 1) {
                Console.Clear ();
                Console.WriteLine ("Playing Blackjack!" + "\n");
                games [0].PlayGames (); //ensures user will get blackjack
            }
            if (n == 2) {
                Console.Clear ();
                Console.WriteLine ("Playing the Quarter Game!" + "\n");
                games [1].PlayGames (); //ensures user will get quartergame
            }
            while (n != 0 && n != 1 && n != 2) {
                Console.WriteLine ("Try another game!");
                n = UIF.PromptInt ("Please enter an integer: ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That depends if `Main` is even declared. Also, a `Main` method will require a array of string parameters. So try calling `Main(null);`

Comment: @William This is Main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to put displaying menu & getting input into a function. Just to make it easy to comprehend. Also in your list of games, maybe you want to keep track of game history? if so you need to keep adding a new one like so:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using ConsoleApplication8;

namespace IntroCS
{
    public class PlayCasino
    {
        private static Random rand = new Random();
        private static List<Casino> games = new List<Casino>();

        private static const int INVALID_CODE = -111;
        private static const int EXIT_CODE = 4;
        public static void Main()
        {

            int choosen = INVALID_CODE;
            while (choosen != EXIT_CODE)
            {
                switch (choosen)
                {
                    case INVALID_CODE:
                        choosen = DisplayMenu();
                        break;
                    case 0:
                        displayHelp();
                        choosen = INVALID_CODE;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        games.Add(new BlackJack());
                        games[games.Count-1].PlayGames();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        games.Add(new QuarterGame());
                        games[games.Count-1].PlayGames();
                        break;
                    default:
                        DisplayMenu();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        private static void displayHelp()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Accessing the Help Menu!" + "\n");// this is where we will print directions/ help menus
        }

        private static int DisplayMenu()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MAIN MENU");
            Console.WriteLine("(0 for help)");
            Console.WriteLine("(1 for blackjack)");
            Console.WriteLine("(2 for Quarter Game)");
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter an integer to choose your game: ");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            int number;
            if (Int32.TryParse(input, out number))
                return number;
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please Try an Integer");
                return INVALID_CODE;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll give that a try and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Your while is repeating the wrong stuff:

```
public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("MAIN MENU");
        Console.WriteLine ("(0 for help)");
        Console.WriteLine ("(1 for blackjack)");
        Console.WriteLine ("(2 for Quarter Game)");
        int n = UIF.PromptInt ("Please enter an integer to choose your game: ");
        games = new List<Casino> ();
        games.Add (new HelpMenu ());
        games.Add (new BlackJack ());
        games.Add (new QuarterGame ());

        while (n != 0 && n != 1 && n != 2) {
            if (n == 0) {
                Console.WriteLine ("Accessing the Help Menu!" + "\n");// this is where we will print directions/ help menus
                Console.WriteLine ("MAIN MENU");
                Console.WriteLine ("(0 for help)");
                Console.WriteLine ("(1 for blackjack)");
                Console.WriteLine ("(2 for Quarter Game)");
            }
            if (n == 1) {
                Console.Clear ();
                Console.WriteLine ("Playing Blackjack!" + "\n");
                games [0].PlayGames (); //ensures user will get blackjack
            }
            if (n == 2) {
                Console.Clear ();
                Console.WriteLine ("Playing the Quarter Game!" + "\n");
                games [1].PlayGames (); //ensures user will get quartergame
            }

            Console.WriteLine ("Try another game!");
            n = UIF.PromptInt ("Please enter an integer: ");
        }
    }
```

Notice you never left the "Main" function, so in your "PlayGames" function you can just go ahead and return:

```
public void PlayGames ()
{
    String replay = "";
    var a = PlayBlackjack (r, replay);
    Console.WriteLine ();
    while (a == "yes") {
        a = PlayBlackjack (r, replay);
        if (a == "no") {
            Console.WriteLine ("Okay, goodbye!");
            return;
        }
    }
    //Do nothing, the while in Main function will already take us back to the menu
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that help. I'll change that. Do you know the answer to the question, by chance?

Comment: Sorry, that code was meant to answer the question, but I didn't realize it was incomplete

Comment: Yes, because it is an interface, I need to return to Main to get back to the Main menu.

Comment: notice I edited the answer to be complete, try running it

Comment: using "return;" ends the game entirely. I just tried to run it.

Comment: have you tried running it step by step? add a breakpoint on `return;` and see what's going on